# SSI Not Working on Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache 2.4.18

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, ssi

I'm trying to run bWAPP SSI injection lesson. However it seems SSI doesn't work on my computer. I'm using PHP 5.6.30 and Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04. I've added the following to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but not working

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bWAPP/>
    Options +Includes
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</Directory>
```

Adding the following to `/var/www/html/bWAPP/.htaccess` is also not working

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

I've restarted the Apache server but still not working.
Is there anything I have to do to enable SSI?

Answer (score -1):

To enable ssl on Ubuntu/Apache-WebServer you need to take next steps on command line:

1. a2enmod ssl
2. a2ensite default-ssl.conf
3. service apache2 restart

For specific virtual host just copy default-ssl.conf to, for example, bwapp.conf and change that file similar to look like this

```
    ServerName  bwapp.youserver.com
    ServerAlias www.bwapp.yourserver.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourserver.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bwapp/

    <Directory /var/www/html/bwapp>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
```

After that, enable this virtual host from command line

1. a2ensite bwapp.conf
2. service apache2 restart

Good luck.

Comment: It is about ssi, not ssl